# php active record authentication can't connection lap server

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I need to authenticate user in active directory in php (using yii framewrok).
On one of computer in the network I have virtual machine with windows 2008 server with active directory (port 5000 is used) and I try to connect it using ldap and authenticate user. Controller name is (server1.domain_name).

My code is like this one:

```
$hostName = '192.168.139.94'; 
$port = 5000;

$userName = 'User1@domain_name';
$password = 'password';

$ldap = ldap_connect($hostName, $port);
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $userName, $password)) {
    echo 'success';
    // log them in!
} else {
    // error message
    echo 'failed';
}
```

But get warning:

```
ldap_bind() [<a href='function.ldap-bind'>function.ldap-bind</a>]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Could you please tell what's the problem? How to get more information what causes problem?

Comment: It looks like 389 port was used not 5000.

Answer (score 2):

Very strange port 5000 for Active-Directory. Native Active-Directory waits on 389, and Lightweigh Directory Server (LDS) naturaly waits on port **50000**, when AD exists on the machine. Are you sure for the port ?

Once the port verified, you can add these two lines between `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind`

```
ldap_connec(...)
ldap_set_option ($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a silly error, 389 port was used, not 5000. I was simply misinformed. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that 389 port was use not 5000.

Comment: I give the good answer, why don't you put it as good answer ?